# How do I change the cgroup version for podman

Tags: containers, cgroups, podman

I am trying to run podman with cgroups v2 enabled. I found a couple of blogposts explaining how to change the runtime to *crun* and the *cgroup_manager* to *cgroupfs*. But I don't know how to actually set the cgroup version to v2.

I am running podman on Manjaro Linx Kernerl 5.4, so, if i am correct, cgroups v2 should be supported.

here it the output of podman info:

```
host:
  BuildahVersion: 1.14.3
  CgroupVersion: v1
  Conmon:
    package: Unknown
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.0.15, commit: 1bddbf7051a973f4a4fecf06faa0c48e82f1e9e1'
  Distribution:
    distribution: manjaro
    version: unknown
  IDMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 65536
      size: 66536
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 65536
      size: 66536
  MemFree: 9938743296
  MemTotal: 16709140480
  OCIRuntime:
    name: crun
    package: Unknown
    path: /usr/bin/crun
    version: |-
      crun version 0.13
      commit: e79e4de4ac16da0ce48777afb72c6241de870525
      spec: 1.0.0
      +SYSTEMD +SELINUX +APPARMOR +CAP +SECCOMP +EBPF +YAJL
  SwapFree: 18296258560
  SwapTotal: 18296258560
  arch: amd64
  cpus: 6
  eventlogger: journald
  hostname: josef-pc
  kernel: 5.4.30-1-MANJARO
  os: linux
  rootless: true
  slirp4netns:
    Executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    Package: Unknown
    Version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.0.0
      commit: a3be729152a33e692cd28b52f664defbf2e7810a
      libslirp: 4.1.0
  uptime: 18m 20.54s
registries:
  search:
  - docker.io
  - registry.fedoraproject.org
  - quay.io
  - registry.access.redhat.com
  - registry.centos.org
store:
  ConfigFile: /home/josmos/.config/containers/storage.conf
  ContainerStore:
    number: 0
  GraphDriverName: overlay
  GraphOptions:
    overlay.mount_program:
      Executable: /usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs
      Package: Unknown
      Version: |-
        fusermount3 version: 3.9.1
        fuse-overlayfs: version 0.7.8
        FUSE library version 3.9.1
        using FUSE kernel interface version 7.31
  GraphRoot: /home/josmos/.local/share/containers/storage
  GraphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: extfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "false"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  ImageStore:
    number: 9
  RunRoot: /run/user/1000/containers
  VolumePath: /home/josmos/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
```

Answer (score 3):

are you using OpenRC?  From what I see, you need to set `rc_cgroup_mode="unified"` in the `rc.conf` file.

If you were using systemd instead, you'd need to run `# grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1"`.

Comment: I had the same question for ubuntu20.04. I ended up having to edit /etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg followed by update-grub followed by reboot to get podman info to show cgroups v2.  When you run update-grub you will see the cfg files you want to look at. I had started with /etc/default/grub, but that didn't cause the parameter to get passed in .

Comment: Hello, how to enable this on non systemd linux like on WSL2. I need to turn podman stats on WSL2 but seems it stuck on cgroup v1 no matter what config I set on podman config